# I am trying to bring named ranges from Excel sheet to R by using xlsx package

Tags: r, r-s4

Below is my code:

```
library("xlsx")
Workbook <- loadWorkbook("Inputs/Rough_Excel.xlsx")
Sheet <- getSheets(Workbook)[["Sheet1"]]
Ranges <- getRanges(Workbook)
Ranges
```

Output:

```
>Ranges
[[1]]
[1] "Java-Object{org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFName@528e6c29}"

[[2]]
[1] "Java-Object{org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFName@ba25a409}"
```

I have provided just an example above. I am sorry, I cannot write the exact complete code as it contains some company specific information. There are two name ranges in this workbook. Could you please help me to get the correct output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried and set out your expected answer. Check out [mre] and [ask]

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Please let me know if I have to redraft it again ?

Comment: Check out the SO guidance links in the "closed" banner at the head of your question for guidance.